# How to incorporate 2nd div into 1st div to be visible and collapsed pressing an arrow button

Tags: jquery, css, html, webforms

I am trying to achieve what could be for you guys a simple task.

I am working in a WebForms project. I am a noob at it, I learned MVC first. I have an update panel (the "Tareas" section) with a couple of divs inside it. The function of this panel is to save some data. Next, I have another div (the "Documentos" section). The function of this div is to save an attachment. The problem is, that right now, I just have a div under another div, and visually it seems to be two separated things. It looks like this:

[image: Original Design]

What the client really want is to have the "documentos" section to be a collapsible section inside the "Tareas" section. The second section (second div) should open and close pressing an arrow button. It should look like this:

[image: Example 1][image: Example 2]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: There are very many tutorials to making collapsible elements, try a google query for "collapsible div".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this implementation. I am not displaying the main content. It will only appear if you click the arrow and it will toggle it with jQuery. Hope this helps.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/159f3zhj/1/)

```js
$(".arrowDown").click(function(){
  $(".arrowDown").toggleClass("animate");
 $(".content").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.box .arrowDown{
  margin-right: 10%;
  font-size: 4em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.arrowUp{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin-right: 10%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.animate{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.content{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div id="documentos">DOCUMENTOS</div>
  <div id="documentos2">0 DOCUMENTOS</div>
  <div class="arrowDown">&darr; </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, aut non! Perspiciatis quisquam rerum placeat odit, aut sed culpa quibusdam ipsam quo! Explicabo facilis aperiam dolores praesentium culpa, blanditiis officiis.</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. With some minor tweaks, I was able to make this work. I just changed a bit the html to make use of an icon for the arrow and added a class to rotate it back to the original position. Thank you!!!!